# Powershell array of list objects

Tags: arrays, powershell, f5

I am trying to write a script which takes a text file of f5 LTM results and puts this into a searchable array so i can compare results from yesterday to today.

This is an example of the file;

```
MemberCount  : 2
Name         : /Common/blah1
Availability : AVAILABILITY_STATUS_GREEN
Enabled      : ENABLED_STATUS_ENABLED
Status       : The pool is available

MemberCount  : 2
Name         : /Common/blah2
Availability : AVAILABILITY_STATUS_GREEN
Enabled      : ENABLED_STATUS_ENABLED
Status       : The pool is available
```

So ideally I would like to make Name the unique field and the sort the list so i can compare the changes in status from yesterday to today.

Here is the code I am working on to email the results but it only provides line by line difference where I would rather get the object changes in the email.

```
Add-PSSnapIn iControlSnapIn

$f5_hosts = '192.168.x.x', '192.168.x.x'
$uid = 'xx'
$pwd ='xx'


foreach($f5_host in $f5_hosts){
$f5_host_out = $(get-date -f yyyyMMdd)+"_"+$f5_host+".txt"
$f5_host_out_yesterday = $((get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyyMMdd'))+"_"+$f5_host+".txt"

#Check login details and generate LTM output file for $f5_host
Initialize-F5.iControl -HostName $f5_host -Username $uid -password $pwd
Get-F5.LTMPool | out-file $f5_host_out

#// Check if EMP file for yesterday exists and send results else send error 
if (Test-Path $f5_host_out_yesterday){
$f5_host_Result = compare-object -ReferenceObject (Get-Content $f5_host_out) -DifferenceObject (Get-Content $f5_host_out_yesterday )
$f5_host_out_yesterday+": file is Present!"
$Text_Body = $f5_host+": difference `r`n"
$Text_Body += ($f5_host_Result | out-string)
Send-MailMessage -to simon.thomason@racq.com.au -from simon.thomason@racq.com.au -subject $f5_host+": F5 Daily LTM Check" -body $Text_Body -smtpserver mailrelay.racqgroup.local
}else{
$f5_host_out_yesterday+": is not file is Present!"
Send-MailMessage -to simon.thomason@racq.com.au -from simon.thomason@racq.com.au -subject $f5_host+": Check failed" -body "Yesterday's file is not present" -smtpserver mailrelay.racqgroup.local
}
}

#Limit File retention to 30days.
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
#Get script location
$path = Get-Location

# Delete files older than the $limit.
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force
```

So as an output I would just want to see something like this in a email

```
Difference From yesterday to today

Yesterday
MemberCount  : 2
Name         : /Common/blah1
Availability : AVAILABILITY_STATUS_GREEN
Enabled      : ENABLED_STATUS_ENABLED
Status       : The pool is available

Today
MemberCount  : 2
Name         : /Common/blah1
Availability : AVAILABILITY_STATUS_RED
Enabled      : ENABLED_STATUS_ENABLED
Status       : The pool is available
```

Comment: Please tell me that you didn't actually include the login info for your F5 in your script there.

Comment: No not at all. It is a Test VM. Production f5 have single factor logins.

Comment: Ok, just making sure, in case you needed to go change your F5 login now :)

Comment: If you want to compare properties of objects from day to day try saving them using `export-clixml` and loading them with `import-clixml` so that you can have actual objects to work with not just arrays of strings.

Comment: that was one of my other questions i how do i store a hash of the password so I do not need to store it in plain text.

Comment: That gets more complicated. You can encrypt the password, but it'll be encrypted by the account and machine, so you need to export the password with the account that will be running this regularly (probably a service account?). Let me see if I still have my example scripts for that, I know I've helped people do it before.

Comment: Hi, I might of overstated my coding abilities. I pretty much got that script for trial and error of other people code which I found with Google. I have been able to use the export-clixml but now need to work out the compare and how to output this to an file.

Comment: OK, how about you update the question to show what you would like the output to look like, and we'll see if we can't get you there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, on your second question, exporting and importing passwords, the encryption is done per user (and I'm pretty sure per machine), so you can't export it, and then have another account import it, but for just straight saving an encrypted password you can use these functions:

```
Function Out-EncryptedPasswordFile{
[cmdletbinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]$Password,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateScript({If(Test-Path (Split-Path $_)){$true}else{Throw "Unable to create file, directory '$(Split-Path $_)\' does not exist."} })][String]$Path
)
    ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Set-Content $Path -Encoding Unicode
}

#Usage Example
#Out-EncryptedPasswordFile TestP@ssw0rd c:\temp\password.txt

Function Import-EncryptedPasswordFile{
[cmdletbinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})][string]$Path
)
    $SSPassword = Get-Content $Path | ConvertTo-SecureString
    $Ptr = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToCoTaskMemUnicode($SSPassword)
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringUni($Ptr)
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ZeroFreeCoTaskMemUnicode($Ptr)
}

#Usage Example
#Import-EncryptedPasswordFile C:\temp\password.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

not certain if right or wrong but this gave the result I was looking for. json was just used so I could store the object and convert it back to powershell object.

```
Add-PSSnapIn iControlSnapIn

$f5_hosts = 'x.x.x.x', 'x.x.x.x'
$uid = 'xx'
$pwd ='xx'


foreach($f5_host in $f5_hosts){
$f5_host_out = $(get-date -f yyyyMMdd)+"_"+$f5_host+".json"
$f5_host_out_yesterday = $((get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyyMMdd'))+"_"+$f5_host+".json"

#Check login details and generate LTM output file for $f5_host
Initialize-F5.iControl -HostName $f5_host -Username $uid -password $pwd
Get-F5.LTMPool | ConvertTo-Json |  out-file $f5_host_out


#// Check if EMP file for yesterday exists and send results else send error 
if (Test-Path $f5_host_out_yesterday){

$f5_host_json_today = Get-Content -Raw $f5_host_out | ConvertFrom-Json
$f5_host_json_yesterday = Get-Content -Raw $f5_host_out_yesterday | ConvertFrom-Json


$f5_host_Result = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject ($f5_host_json_today | Sort-Object ) -DifferenceObject ($f5_host_json_yesterday | Sort-Object ) -property MemberCount, Name, Status, Availability, Enabled, Status | sort-object -property Name
#$f5_host_Result
$f5_host_out_yesterday+": file is Present!"
$Text_Body = $f5_host+": difference `r`n"
$Text_Body += ($f5_host_Result | out-string)
Send-MailMessage -to y@x -from y@x -subject $f5_host+": F5 Daily LTM Check" -body $Text_Body -smtpserver blah
}else{
$f5_host_out_yesterday+": is not file is Present!"
Send-MailMessage -to y@x -from y@x -subject $f5_host+": Check failed" -body "Yesterday's file is not present" -smtpserver blah
}
}

#Limit File retention to 30days.
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
#Get script location
$path = Get-Location

# Delete files older than the $limit.
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force
```